# asp.net gridview nested after opening modal form problem collapse items

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I use a nested GridView, based on the following example

[https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Nested-GridView-with-Expand-Collapse-example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

After opening a modal form, all items that are open are closed. I understand that it's about AutoPostBack and I can't turn it off for other reasons...

I would like to ask for help

Code Behind VB

```
Me.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Form.GetType(), "Show", "ShowModalForm('" & "myModal" & "', '" & "Title" & "', '" & "Message" & "');", True)
```

Html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowModalForm(NamePopup, title, message) {
        $("#myModal .data-toggle").html("modal");
        $("#myModal .data-target").html("#myModal");
        $("#" + NamePopup).modal("show");
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("body").on("click", "[src*=plus-square]", function () {
        $("[src*=dash-square]").each(function () {
            $(this).trigger('click');
        });
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan ='999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "src/dash-square.svg");
    });
    $("body").on("click", "[src*=dash-square]", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "src/plus-square.svg");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
</script>


<asp:GridView
                ID="myDataTable"
                DataKeyNames="DOWO_ID"
                runat="server"
                OnRowDataBound="myDataTable_RowDataBound">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="src/plus-square.svg" />
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none;">

                                        <asp:GridView
                                            ID="myOrders"
                                            DataKeyNames="DOWOI_ID"
                                            runat="server">
                                            <Columns>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="DOWOI_ID" HeaderText="ID" />
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="DOWO_ID" HeaderText="ID Items" />
                                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" OnClick="Display">Otvori</asp:LinkButton>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                            </Columns>
                                        </asp:GridView>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DOWO_ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="DOWO_ID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DOWO_BarCode" HeaderText="Barcode" SortExpression="DOWO_BarCode" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DOWO_Order" HeaderText="BN" SortExpression="DOWO_Order" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
             <div class="modal-content">

....

            </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

I tried inserting an UpdatePanel in front of the nested grid, but to no avail, the modal form call then doesn't work at all. I also tried to show and keep the panel open in the code behind while the modal form is open but again to no avail. I believe there is a solution by using UpdatePanel or through jquery, but I don't know how...

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:GridView> 

            ...

        </asp:GridView>
        
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="myOrders" />
    </Triggers>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Can someone help me, is the question asked correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I simple going to suggest/state that bootstrap dialogs are beyond painful, they just are.

So, not only do you want to pop a dialog, but you need one that can survive post-backs. In "most" cases, any post-back will collapse the dialog.

However, (hopefully) you already have jQuery installed.

so, then adopt the jQuery.UI library. Those dialogs might look a bit "old" style wise (you can fix that with some love and care), but those dialogs just work, they rock, and they can be placed in a update panel, and they CAN survive and play nice with a udpate panel.

Not only that, but jQuery.UI dialogs "make sense"

You know, you drop a button on a form, have some click event that calls some code that pops a dialog, and it shows. All nice simple code. Contrast that to those bootstrap dialogs. You build up a complex div, add a boatload of classes, and some place, some how, some where in code these things are supposed to magic pop up? As such, not only are bootstrap dialogs difficult to setup, they are a beyond horror night mare to support, and extend.

Next up:

I don't recommend trying to nest 2 grid views, but suggest the top most one is a list view. It turns out that "when" your gv starts to get complex, then they become rather messy to work with. (You have what you have now, so this is just a good fyi).

OK, so let's setup a example of say some rows on a grid view (I'll use a list view). And in side of that list view, we have button to expand, and it expands a gridview.

Nothing real special. but, say this:

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
            <td><asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="+" onclick="cmdView_Click" 
                cssclass="btn" Width="40px"/></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="HotelNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="CityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="ProvinceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Province") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td id="mygridview" colspan="5" runat="server" style="display:none">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" style="margin-left:3%;width:97%"  >
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Firstname" HeaderText="Firstname" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"   />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"           />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" HeaderStyle-Width="140px"
                            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                            <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdEdit" runat="server"
                            CssClass="btn btn-default"
                            ImageUrl="~/Content/Icons/pencil-square.svg"
                            OnClick="cmdEdit_Click"
                            />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" style="margin-left:12px"
                            CssClass="btn btn-default"
                            ImageUrl="~/Content/Icons/trash.svg"
                            />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        
            <asp:Button ID="cmdAddRow" runat="server" Text="+"
                style="float:right;margin-right:5px" Width="40px"
                OnClick="cmdAddRow_Click"                 
                />
            </td>
            </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" class = "table table-hover" >
            <tr runat="server" style="">
                <th runat="server">View</th>
                <th runat="server">HotelName</th>
                <th runat="server">City</th>
                <th runat="server">Province</th>
                <th runat="server">Description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
            </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

And code to load, looks like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()
    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"

    ListView1.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL)
    ListView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And we now see/have this:

[image]

So, the above uses a pop up (a Jquery.ui one).

You note that it can/does surive post-backs.

A jquery.UI dialog simple requires you need it a "div" with whatever inside.

How about we take the WHOLE above mess, shove it into a div, and then pop that!!!

So, we now have this:

[image]

So, we have post-backs, and now we nested TWO dialogs deep!!!

So, how to setup a popup.

Well, in the most basic format, you have this:

First, we have that "+" button to expand one listview row (child is gv).

That code is this:

```
Protected Sub cmdView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim cmd As Button = sender
    Dim gVR As ListViewDataItem = cmd.Parent   ' get current row
    Dim gChild As GridView = gVR.FindControl("GridView2")   ' pluck grid for this row
    Dim MyDiv As HtmlTableCell = gVR.FindControl("mygridview")

    If MyDiv.Style("display") = "normal" Then
        ' if grid is already display, then hide it, and exit
        MyDiv.Style("display") = "none"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MyDiv.Style("display") = "normal"

    Dim HotelPK As String = ListView1.DataKeys(gVR.DataItemIndex).Item("ID")

    ' only re-load if never loaded
    If gChild.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        Dim strSQL As String
        strSQL = "SELECT * from People where hotel_id = " & HotelPK
        gChild.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL)
        gChild.DataBind()

    End If

End Sub
```

Not too much code. Note VERY close the user of the naming container trick.

so, that displays the nested gv.

And in that nested gv, I have a edit button click. that's our FIRST example of using a jQuery.UI dialog.

The gv button is this:

```
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"           />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" HeaderStyle-Width="140px"
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdEdit" runat="server"
                CssClass="btn btn-default"
                ImageUrl="~/Content/Icons/pencil-square.svg"
                OnClick="cmdEdit_Click"
                />

            <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" style="margin-left:12px"
                CssClass="btn btn-default"
                ImageUrl="~/Content/Icons/trash.svg"
                />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

(I ommited most of the markup).

So, when we click that button in the gv row?

We get the row information.
Place the row information into a "handy div"

Pop the div.

so, button code is this:

```
Protected Sub cmdEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' nested grid edit button.
    Dim cmdEdit As ImageButton = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = cmdEdit.NamingContainer
    Dim GV As GridView = gRow.NamingContainer
    Dim PkID As Integer = GV.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")

    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * from People WHERE ID = " & PkID
    Dim rstData As DataTable = MyRst(strSQL)

    ' load up our edit div
    With rstData.Rows(0)
        txtFirstname.Text = .Item("FirstName").ToString
        txtLastname.Text = .Item("LastName").ToString
        txtCity.Text = .Item("City").ToString
        If IsDBNull(.Item("Active")) Then
            Active.Checked = False
        Else
            Active.Checked = .Item("Active")
        End If
        txtNotes.Text = .Item("Notes").ToString
    End With

    Session("RowPK") = PkID
    ' save current list view row
    Dim LV As ListViewItem = GV.NamingContainer
    Session("LvRow") = LV.DataItemIndex
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.UpdatePanel1, Me.UpdatePanel1.GetType, "MyPop", "MyEdit()", True)

End Sub
```

Again, most of that code is "plain jane". Nothing to call mom about.

However, that last line? We want to pop the div, and thus AFTER we load up the div, we will pop it.

That div is/was placed below all of our listview/gridview markup.

Really again, plain jane markup. This:

```
<div id="myedit" style="float: left; width: 20%; display: none">
    <div style="text-align: right">
        <p>First Name :<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstname" runat="server" Width="150"></asp:TextBox></p>
        <p>Last Name :<asp:TextBox ID="txtLastname" runat="server" Width="150"></asp:TextBox></p>
        <p>City  :<asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Width="150"></asp:TextBox></p>
        <p>Active :<asp:CheckBox ID="Active" runat="server" Width="150"></asp:CheckBox></p>
        <br />
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: right">
        Notes :
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" 
            Width="240px" TextMode="MultiLine" 
            Height="71px">
        </asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btn" Width="90px" />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn" Width="90px"
            OnClientClick="$('#myedit').dialog('close');$('#myedit').dialog('destroy');return false;" Style="margin-left: 8px" />
    </div>
</div>

       <script>
            function MyEdit() {
                var myDialog = $("#myedit");
                myDialog.dialog({
                    title: "Edit Hotel Information",
                    modal: true,
                    width: "280px",
                    resizable: false,
                    appendTo: "form",
                    autoOpen: false
                });
                myDialog.dialog('open');
           }
        </script>
```

So, yes, a bit of js code. But, note how we don't have some "horrid" mess of a boatload of bs classes here. Just a simple div, and some readable js code to pop the jQuery.ui.

So, if you need/want/will/enjoy a pop dialog, and one that can "withstand" post-backs (and remember, a update-panel does NOT prevent post-backs, it only hides and makes it look like a post-back is not occurring, but they do post-back, and up's even trigger the page load event each time).

So, to pop a dialog, but with a update panel (so it does not collopse with working code and buttons that post back?).

Then just wrap your code in a update panel, and make sure the "div" in question wraps the update panel.

So, like this:

```
    <div id="Everything" style="width:40%">

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

     ' you stuff you want to pop here
```

So, note the pattern:

```
  Your div to pop
  the update panel
  stuff inside
  end update 
  end div
```

So, for the 2nd demo, I just created a div that wraps up the WHOLE div around the listview.

So, then I just created a button to pop the WHOLE she-bang.

That button code was this:

```
    <asp:Button ID="cmdEverythingPop" runat="server"  style="display:normal"
        Text="Pop the whole meal deal!"
        CssClass="btn btn-default" 
        OnClientClick="MyEditAll();return false"
        />
    <br />
    <br />


    <div id="Everything" style="width:40%">

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
         .etc. etc. etc.
```

And the js code for that button was this:

```
<script>
        function MyEditAll() {
            var myDialog2 = $("#Everything");
            myDialog2.dialog({
                title: "Bookings editor",
                modal: true,
                width: "60%",
                resizable: false,
                autoOpen: false,
                appendTo: "form",
                buttons: {
                    AllDone: function () {
                        myDialog2.dialog('close')
                    }
                }
            });
            myDialog2.dialog('open');
        }
    </script>
```

So again, note how the jQuery.UI dialog simple requires that you feed it a "div".

Put your up's panel + content inside of that div (such as your gv example), and it should not only pop up nice, but also allow post-backs, and not collapse).

I do as a general rule place the js code INSIDE of the up panel area - at the botton. I not had much time to test if you can place that code outside of the UP - you probably can.

So, there is a boatload of REALLY great ideas in above. Note how for both the listview, and the gridview, I use the naming container trick.

And I did use this helper routine to save code and world poverty:

```
Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            rstData.TableName = strSQL
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData
End Function
```

and the only other real part was ensure that you have jQuery, jQuery.UI available to the code in that page.

Comment: Wow, I followed your work even before writing the post, honestly, I didn't like the look of the modal form, but the ability to move around the screen is now more reason to think about it. Also, in the meantime I solved the problem, how reliable it will be as you say, time will tell, certainly this proposal of yours is valuable and I think it will help me and others. Thank you very much for the effort and time you have dedicated.

Comment: You could try the same with the boostrap dialog, and place (wrap) the div with the update panel. As noted, I far MORE prefer that if you have some button on a page, you click on that button, it calls say some js routine, and that routine then pops the dialog system.  Using a jQuery.UI dialog might be a few more lines of code then all those "class" settings, but then it results in code that you can change, follow, modify, and such code makes a whole lot more sense to read.  And yes, my only real gripe with jQuery.UI dialogs is they don't look great unless you give them some love and care.

Comment: Here's how I solved the problem. I manage completely on the server side directly from the code, the only complaint is that the page always flickers but ok. https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Multilevel-N-Level-Nested-GridView-GridView-inside-GridView-in-ASPNet-with-Paging.aspx

Comment: As I pointed out, I feel the listview is cleaner, and you wind up with more control. The expanding of the child gv tends to NOT play well if the parent is also a gv. You can beat it with a frying pan, and can get this to work, but I found the listview for the parent is far more clean of a setup. And better yet, you don't need a boatload of template fields over and over. With list view, it just clean markup, and you free to drop in any asp.net control, and do so without having to resort to all those template tags. Not a huge deal - and just suggesting that listviews tend to be better for this

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try with the listview control, the most important thing for me is to have the possibility of expansion

Comment: Actually, either road (listview or gv) is fine. However, the MORE valuable goal here is that you want such expand/collapse ability and you want this inside of a dialog. (even if you don't have that 2nd pop up edit example, the expand/contract is a post-back, and as above shows, that is 100% legal and works fine with a jQuery.UI dialog. In other words, unlike the bootstrap dialogs, we can enjoy post-backs in that pop dialog. I don't believe that is possible with bootstrap dialogs - but it is with jQuery.UI ones if you use a update panel, and the examples above shows this in action

Comment: ok now you have me intrigued, can you give me some guidelines to integrate GridView (header) and ListView (items). I found a few suggestions, however the ListView is mainly intended for displaying items, however I have a requirement to interact with the items (add, modify, delete). I use Bootstrap primarily because the whole project is in it, it's also responsive and I can easily affect the rules when the app is used on a phone or computer...